# Ordenar por custom fields e por data de publicação

Tags: javascript, wordpress, classificação, order-by

Meu problema é o seguinte, tenho um post_type no nome de "colecoes" e dentro dele várias postagens com campos personalizados "situacao-da-peca" e "colecao-da-peca". O resultado desses dois campos são números, para ficar mais fácil de ordenar. 
Consegui ajuda pra ordernar esses campos personalizados através de um javascript, como no código abaixo, e funciona perfeitamente. Porém, preciso também que dentro dessa ordenação os posts também fiquem ordenados por data de publicação. No Firefox essa ordem está certinha, porém no Chrome e IE, a ordem por data (padrão do wordpress, por sinal), não funciona. Sei que é o javascript que pode estar desordenando elas, mas não sei como corrigir...
Segue o link que isso está acontecendo: https://malumacedo.com.br/marca/basico-brasil/

```html
<ol id="pecas">
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'colecoes'); 
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args); 
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
<li class="foto" data-char="<?php if( get_field('situacao-da-peca') == '1' ):?>c<?php the_field('colecao-da-peca');?><?php endif;?><?php if( get_field('situacao-da-peca') == '2' ):?>b<?php the_field('colecao-da-peca');?><?php endif;?><?php if( get_field('situacao-da-peca') == '3' ):?>a<?php the_field('colecao-da-peca');?><?php endif;?>">
<div class="imagem"></div>
</li>
<?php endwhile; endif;?>
</ol>
<script>
$("#pecas li").sort(sort_li).appendTo('#pecas');
function sort_li(a, b){
 var r = /[a-z]/; 
    var aD = $(a).data('char');
    var bD = $(b).data('char');
    var va = aD.charCodeAt(0);
   var vb = bD.charCodeAt(0);
   if(va == vb){ 
      var aN = parseInt(aD.replace(r, ''));
      var bN = parseInt(bD.replace(r, ''));
      return bN > aN ? 1 : -1;
   }

   return vb > va ? 1 : -1;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer essa ordenação no **Wordpress** da seguinte maneira:

```
$args  = array( 'post_type'=>'colecoes', 'orderby'=>'date', 'order'=>'DESC' ); // order pode ser ASC ou DESC
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Mais informações sobre quais campos você pode utilizar na ordenação no link abaixo.
[Documentação](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Você falou que conseguiu ordenar pelos *custom fields* com *javascript* e que funciona perfeitamente, mas se você quiser fazer essa ordenação pelo *Wordpress* é só dar uma olhada nessa [documentação](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/orde-posts-by-custom-fields/).

Comment: Já havia tentando isso, esse comando não funciona também, no Google Chrome nem no IE. Elas deveriam ficar ordenadas como está no Firefox (que está certinho pela ordem de postagem), esse é o link https://malumacedo.com.br/todas-as-colecoes/ . É como se eles ordenassem aleatoriamente e só seguissem o comando do javascript mesmo. Estou estudando essa ordenação por custom fields, pra ver se acho um caminho. Obrigada